# Multiple checkbox total value and apply discount

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a running total and then if more than one checkbox is selected to apply a discount.

Price is based on time.So...
Back massage = 30 minutes = $50
Neck massage = 30 minutes = $50
Legs and feet = 30 minutes = $50
Total = (if one selected then price = $50)
if more than one then apply discount of $25
on submit an email will be sent to the client. So its not an ecommerce site thereofore not necassary to do server side calculations.

This is my code at the moment:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkTotal() {
        document.listForm.total.value = '';
        var sum = 0;
        for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice.length;i++) {
          if (document.listForm.choice[i].checked) {
            sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice[i].value);
          }
        }
        document.listForm.total.value = sum;
    }
</script>

<form name="listForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="50" onChange="checkTotal()"/>Back Massage - 30 Minutes<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="50" onChange="checkTotal()"/>Neck Massage - 30 minutes<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="50" onChange="checkTotal()"/>Shoulder Massage - 30 Minutes<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="30" onChange="checkTotal()"/>Head Massage - 15 minutes<br/>
Total: <input type="text" size="2" name="total" value="0"/>
</form>
```

Comment: doesn't your code work or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function checkTotal() {
        document.listForm.total.value = '';
        var sum = 0;        var o = 0;
        for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice.length;i++) {
          if (document.listForm.choice[i].checked) {
            sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.choice[i].value);
              o++;
          }
        }
     if (o>1) {sum=sum-25;}
     document.listForm.total.value = sum;

    }
```

Comment: Ok, you can close the post and check my answer as "correct". Thanks

Comment: Cant seem to find the "close ticket option. Also if I wanted to have 2 totals. One for the full amount and the other showing the discounted amount is that possible?

Comment: Click on the check next left my answer to do it green.